# Racket CLI repl interprets tabs in text sent via tmux as autocomplete

Tags: vim, scheme, racket, tmux, sicp

I'm using vim, tslime, and tmux to send scheme code to the racket repl (v6.7) via the command line. I'm running on Arch Linux.

When I do so, I commonly get the auto-completion warning:

> "Display all [xyz] possibilities (y or n)?"

I'm guessing racket is interpreting the tabs in the snippets of code tmux is sending from vim.

Here's my problem:

**1. Annoying.** How do I get rid of it?

**2. Code needs to be passed twice!** Some code only works properly if I pass it to the racket repl twice in a row. In DrRacket the code works perfectly, so obviously the tabs are preventing the repl from evaluating some s-expressions (and passing the code twice resolves it somehow).

Here is the code, from SICP, 1.2.6:

```
; Smallest divisor
(define (smallest-divisor n) (find-divisor n 2))

(define (find-divisor n test-divisor)
  (cond ((> (square test-divisor) n) n)             ; tests as far as sqrt of n
        ((divides? test-divisor n) test-divisor)
        (else (find-divisor n (+ test-divisor 1)))))

(define (divides? a b) (= (remainder b a) 0))

(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (prime? n)
  (= n (smallest-divisor n)))
```

Here is what this all looks like in the racket repl. Notice how in the first pass below, the the procedure `prime?` evaluates (*incorrectly*) that 10 is prime.

> Welcome to Racket v6.7.
>
> > (define (smallest-divisor n) (find-divisor n 2))
>
> >  (define (find-divisor n test-divisor)
>
> (cond ((> (square test-divisor) n) n) Display all 254 possibilities? (y or n)
>
> (cond ((> (square test-divisor) n) n) Display all 254 possibilities? (y or n)
>
> (cond ((> (square test-divisor) n) n) ; tests as far as sqrt of n
>
> Display all 254 possibilities? (y or n)   (else (find-divisor n (+
>   test-divisor 1)))))
>
> >  (define (divides? a b) (= (remainder b a) 0))
>
> >  (define (square x) (* x x))
>
> >  (define (prime? n)
>
> (= n (smallest-divisor n)))
>
> >  (prime? 10)
>
> #t

Passing the code a second time, we get the following output. And this time, `prime?` *correctly* evaluates that 10 is not prime.

> > (define (smallest-divisor n) (find-divisor n 2))
>
> >   (define (find-divisor n test-divisor)
>
> (cond ((> (square test-divisor) n) n) Display all 258 possibilities? (y or n)
>
> (cond ((> (square test-divisor) n) n) Display all 258 possibilities? (y or n)
>
> (cond ((> (square test-divisor) n) n) ; tests as far as sqrt of n
>
> Display all 258 possibilities? (y or n)   ((divides? test-divisor n)
>   test-divisor)
>
> Display all 258 possibilities? (y or n)   (else (find-divisor n (+
>   test-divisor 1)))))
>
> >   (define (divides? a b) (= (remainder b a) 0))
>
> >   (define (square x) (* x x))
>
> >   (define (prime? n)
>
> (= n (smallest-divisor n)))
>
> >   (prime? 10)
>
> #f
>
> >

Comment: I have a hunch that this more a tmux question than a racket/scheme question.  Consider asking "How do I turn off tab in tmux?" directly.

Comment: There is actually a difference between running a module in DrRacket and just dumping a module’s contents into the REPL: the former actually executes a module, while the latter just executes each of the module’s expressions and forms at the top-level. [And the top level is hopeless.](https://gist.github.com/samth/3083053)